# integrate sinus and cosinus divison

Tags: integration

I'm trying to solve $$\int \frac{1}{\sin^2x+2\cos^2x} dx $$

I thought this should be done using the standard substitution $\tan \dfrac {x}{2} = t$ however that won't work (the integral I then get isn't correct according to wolframalpha). So how do you solve this?

(and why doesn't $\tan \dfrac {x}{2} = t$ work?)

Comment: Hint: $\cos^{2}x+\sin^{2}x=1$.

Comment: That substitution works here. It works for every rational function of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$. If you are getting a different answer it could either be: (1) you made a computation mistake, (2) you forgot to return the result to the original variable $x$, or (3) you actually got the right answer but are missing to notice that the one in wolframalpha is a different but equivalent expression.

Comment: *The integral I then get isn't correct according to Wolfram Alpha* - Sometimes the same expression can be written in two or more ways, both or all of which are equivalent. Either that, or you probably made some small mistake along the way. In any case, I doubt that the Weierstrass substitution doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your integral is
$$\int\dfrac{dx}{1+\cos^2x}$$
and with $t=\tan\left( x\right)$ we have $dx=\dfrac{dt}{1+t^2}$ and $\cos^2 x=\dfrac{1}{1+t^2}$ so we find
$$\int\dfrac{dt}{2+t^2}=\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\int\dfrac{d(t/\sqrt2)}{1+\left(\dfrac t{\sqrt 2}\right)^2}=\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\arctan\left(\dfrac t{\sqrt 2}\right)+C=\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\arctan\left(\dfrac {\tan x}{\sqrt 2}\right)+C  $$

Comment: how to you calculate $dx$ and $cos^2 x$?

Comment: We have $dx=d(\tan(x))=(1+\tan^2(x))dx=(1+t^2)dx$ and we have
$$\frac1{\cos^2x}=1+\tan^2x$$